ERROR 404 Not Found: failed to download rootfs from kali.download
[*] Checking package dependencies...
proot is OK
tar is OK
axel is OK
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
##

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and O not

upgraded. [*] Downloading rootfs...

--2024-09-12 22:31:14-- https://kali.download/nethun ter-images/current/rootfs/kalifs-arm64-full.tar.xz Resolving kali.download (kali.download)... 2606:4700: :6811:fdef, 2606:4700::6811:feef, 104.17.254.239, ... Connecting to kali.download (kali,download) | 2606:4700 ::6811:fdef:443... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2024-09-12 22:31:14 ERROR 404 Not Found



As you can see, the file that it is trying to download is not available. Are you trying to install a version of the software that is too old, maybe? It's hard to tell, because you don't show what command you are using. It looks that your software tries to find the 2024.2 image, but the "current"/2024.3 image file is renamed.

I mean, this was told to you in your previous question. I honestly think you are a prime candidate to carefully read https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ !

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's installing from the wrong url, i think they updated the endpoint but not the installation file. You should edit the shell installation in nano from kalifs-${SYS_ARCH}-${wimg}.tar.xz to kali-nethunter-rootfs-${wimg}-${SYS_ARCH}.tar.xz and the same for the sha512sum where you also have to change the file extension to tar.xz.sha512sum.
